# Use Castle DynamicProxy to rollback property changes

Tags: c#, .net, interceptor, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I've found many examples of DynamicProxy used to perform additional work when property changes in the object, but how do I not only *set* the property value in the interceptor (by calling `Proceed()`), but also *roll it back*, if something went wrong during interception itself?

Usecase here is this: I use settings objects to provide setting values to some parts of the system, so they won't have to work with the configuration backend.

These objects are also `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so if anyone changes the setting at runtime, the component which has the object gets notified about the change and can perform reconfiguration on the fly.

So what I need to do is roll back the change of the property if `PropertyChanged` event handler has thrown an exception (the change led to misconfiguration or was invalid).

I wonder how it can be done.

**I've ended up** using both `INotifyPropertyChanging` (and extended this interface a bit) and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Simply because the validation should be performed *before* the actual setting, because

- order of events is not determined, and so the actual consumer of the setting can get the notification *before* it has been even validated, when you using only `INPChanged`
- and overall the validation and consuming are different and should have different events: one before the setting took place (to prevent it from happening) and one after - when the actual value of the property is already updated (for the code to work as expected).

When I look at this now, the original design (which the question is about) seems bad to me.

Comment: I'd suggest not going down the route of "rolling back" a value, but instead allow the property change to commence. Your model is allowed to be in an invalid state. From there, you can have some other piece of code prevent "saving" or "updating" (I'm assuming that's what your doing) based on the state.

Comment: @m-y Yes, I've ended up validating the value before it was set, and throwing exception, if validation fails. So, instead of quiet rollback, I prominently signal the place where bad code executes and prevent it from proceeding in invalid state.

Comment: (Hence the added INotifyPropertyChanging contract.)

Comment: I realize this, but my suggestion would be to not have any type of rollback mechanism. Instead, allow the model to stay in the invalid state and use IDataErrorInfo to relay the invalid state to the view.